# Assigning value of pointer to static variable

Tags: c, matlab

I have been working on an S-function for matlab in c.But the following code is crashing.My basics in c is very poor :)

```
//
static double a=0;
//

static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{   
    const real_T    *u    = ssGetInputPortRealSignal(S,0);
    a=*u;   //this line creates the problem

}
//
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ssGetInputPortRealSignal` does not return `NULL`?

Comment: It crashes because you dereference an invalid u pointer, whether NULL or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/sfg/ssgetinputportrealsignal.html) doesn't say that the return can be anything else than a pointer, but as commenters have pointed out you should check it for being `NULL` before de-referencing.